# how to retrieve the name of a Gtk.TextBuffer

Tags: python, pygtk, glade

I am using python and pygtk. the interface is described in a glade file. I am programming a generic MPV interface, as generic as I can possibly make it.

I am associating widgets in the glade file to fields in the model, and I would not like to subclass the parent presenter class. I want to retrieve the name of a textbuffer widget, declared in the glade file:

```
<object class="GtkTextBuffer" id="tag_desc_textbuffer">
  <signal name="changed" handler="on_textbuffer_changed" swapped="no"/>
</object>
```

in my *generic* `on_textbuffer_changed` I receive the text buffer instance as a parameter, but how do I get its name?

now I know that you cannot use the field `name` of any widget in order to get its `name`, you need to use a static function like this: `gtk.Buildable.get_name(widget)`.

if I try to do this for `gtk.TextBuffer`, I get this error:

`TypeError: descriptor 'get_name' requires a 'gtk.Buildable' object but received a 'gtk.TextBuffer'`

the `gtk.TextBuffer` does not even know of `id` nor `name`.

```
AttributeError: 'gtk.TextBuffer' object has no attribute 'name'
AttributeError: 'gtk.TextBuffer' object has no attribute 'id'
```

any hints?

I suppose I'm going to write a *dedicated* handler where the name of the widget is already known.

```
def on_tag_desc_textbuffer_changed(self, widget, value=None):
    return GenericEditorPresenter.on_textbuffer_changed(
        self, widget, value, attr='description')
```

I do not like the idea because the minimally subclassed presenter already associates all view.widget_name → model.field_name, including 'tag_desc_textbuffer' to 'description'. I don't like having this information repeated...